# Assignment of one cursor to other cursor and looping through for loop

Tags: oracle, plsql, plsqldeveloper

I have a cursor inside package specification like below

```
Create package pkgname 
is 
      Cursor C1(report_date date) is                select * from some_table where some_date=report_date;
   procedure proc(repdate date)
end;
```

I want a functionality that assign this cursor C1 to other cursor in procedure of the same package body.

```
    Create package body pkgname is
    
         Procedure proc(repdate date)
         Is 
              Cursor C2 is C1(repdate);
    
                  Begin
                      for j in C2 loop
                          --do some task;
                      end loop;
        End;
End;
```

Comment: Welcome to the SO community. Please take a few miunets to go through the [Tour](https://stackoverflow.com/tour) and review the help section [ask]. For this well you ***cannot* assign a cursor to another cursor**. Please describe the issue you are trying to solve not how you think to solve it.

Answer (score 0):

Why would you do that? If you declared the cursor in package specification, simply **use it** in package body. For example:

```
SQL> create or replace package pkg_test as
  2    cursor c1 (par_job varchar2) is
  3      select empno, ename from emp
  4      where job = par_job;
  5    procedure proc (par_job in varchar2);
  6  end;
  7  /

Package created.

SQL> create or replace package body pkg_test as
  2    procedure proc (par_job in varchar2) is
  3    begin
  4      for cur_r in pkg_test.c1(par_job) loop                      --> here it is!
  5        dbms_output.put_line(cur_r.empno ||' '|| cur_r.ename);
  6      end loop;
  7    end;
  8  end;
  9  /

Package body created.

SQL> set serveroutput on
SQL> exec pkg_test.proc('CLERK');
7369 SMITH
7876 ADAMS
7900 JAMES

PL/SQL procedure successfully completed.

SQL>
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. Actually I have two cursors C1, C2 in package specification.  In package body I want to assign the cursor to other cursor based on the condition.

Comment: You can't, as far as I can tell.